# Pushing to a user's list replace old item

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to the firebase world and I'm trying to perform a simple task on a realtime-database, and somehow I can't manage to make it work. I want this kind of structure :

```
"users": {
   "UID_1": {
      "username": "FooBar",
      "email": "foo.bar@mail.com",
      "tasks": {
         "KEY_1": {
            "name": "task1",
            "state": false
         },
         "KEY_2": {
            "name": "task2",
            "state": false
         },
      },
   }
}
```

I'm using javascript on a client side to push a new task for a specific authenticated user, here's the code :

```
firebase.database().ref("users/" + userId + "/tasks").push({
   name: taskName,
   state: state
});
```

Everytime I do that, the old task is being deleted, and the new one added to the "tasks" list.

I've also tried with update, but it doesn't work.

```
var taskListRef = dbRef.ref("users/" + userId + "/tasks");
var newTaskKey = taskListRef.push().key;
var newTaskRef = dbRef.ref("users/" + userId + "/tasks/" + newTaskKey);
newTaskRef .update({
    name: taskName,
    state: state
});
```

Here's a picture showing the old item being replaced on the firebase console :

[image]

Am I missing some really obvious element in here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a '/' at the end of the string '/tasks'. Should be '/tasks/' then push should work. For the update method you would need to modify tasks string as above and also put a '/' after newTaskKey.

Comment: That doesn't work as well, the item in tasks get replaced for some reason even though the TaskID are different.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find the answer, the truth is, I was setting user information on connexion, instead of updating... So the task list was being deleted everytime !